# Conditionally format a cell which has part of its text match any value from a range of cells in a specific column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

In excel 2010 I have 2 columns:

Column A has a list of urls, like:

http://domain.com/12345

http://domain.com/23445

http://domain.com/15321

http://domain.com/97754

Column B has a list of numbers like:

86860

12345

74663

23232

34556

23333

How do I highlight cells in column A which url contains the number that matches any number in in column B?

In other words I need each cell in column A to be checked against every cell in column B and to highlight all the cases where the url in cell from column A contains the number found in any of the cells in column B.

So only the first cell in column A in the example above will be highlighted because it contains the number 12345 from column B.

Thanks

Comment: Are the urls all the same? Will the numbers be always 5 digit long? Will the always be 3 slashes?

Comment: the urls will have the same exact structure before the occurrence of the numbers, numbers however will vary in length by 1-2 digits

Comment: the exact structure will be http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-xxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select entire column `A` and apply Conditional formatting with this formula:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(FIND($B$1:$B$6,A1)))
```

where `$B$1:$B$6` range of all numbers in column `B`

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Oops, was going for `MATCH`. `SEARCH` is definitely simpler!

Comment: Btw, any reason for the `OR`?

Comment: yes, actually it's array formula and `ISNUMBER(...)` returns array `{FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE}` and without `OR` result'd be equal to first element of array

Comment: Awesome, gonna accept as soon as will be allowed, this is exactly what I was looking for!